# gotoIf condition behaves abnormally how to restrict this?

Tags: selenium-ide

Please let me know where code goes wrong? Please give me resolution.

Step 1:  Condition A

Step 2:  If condition A true go to step 4.

Step 3:  Here some actions.

Step 4:  Here some actions

Step 5:   Go to step 3.

So my ultimate aim is

If condition true then do step 4 and continue step 3...
if condition false then do step 3 only.

Here once step 4 is finished step 3 have to be executed as per Step 5. (It is doing correctly)

But once step 3 is executed it should not execute step 4. How to achieve this? (But it is doing again step 4)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Condition A

Step 2: |gotoIf|condition A true|Step6|

Step 3: |label|Step3||

Step 4: Here some actions.

Step 5:|gotoLabel|Step7||

Step 6: |label|Step6||

Step 7: Here some actions.

Step 8: |gotoLabel|Step3||

Step 9: |label|Step7||

Step 10: Here some actions**